# Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1

Tags: typescript, types, arguments, botframework

I have an interface ConfState in type.ts and i imported the interface ConfState in app.ts and when i try to use it i get this error.
Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1.

**type.ts

---

```js
export interface ConfState {
 
}
```

**app.ts

---

```js
import {BotFrameworkAdapter,MemoryStorage,ConversationState} from "botbuilder";
import * as restify from "restify";
import {ConfState} from "./types";

let server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978,() => {
    console.log("${server.name} listening on {server.url}");
});

const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId:process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword:process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

const conversationState = new ConversationState<ConfState>(new MemoryStorage());
adapter.use(conversationState)

server.post("/api/message",(req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req,res, async (context) => {
        if(context.activity.type === "message") {
            const state = conversationState.get(context);
            await context.sendActivity("You said ${context.activity.text}");
        } else {
            await context.sendActivity("${context.activity.type} event detected");
        }
        });
});
```

Comment: Show us what `ConversationState` looks like

Comment: export declare class ConversationState extends BotState {
    private namespace;
    constructor(storage: Storage, namespace?: string);
    getStorageKey(context: TurnContext): string | undefined;
}                                                                                                                                               It looks like this

Answer (score 2):

Remove the generic . An update to the library no longer requires ConversationState to get a generic.

And instead use this:

```
let conversationState;

const memoryStorage = new MemoryStorage();
conversationState = new ConversationState(memoryStorage);
```

Comment: This indeed fixed my error message. I am wondering should memoryStorage be a let as we may need to reassign or even the bot would reassign the memory in case we have to scale teh bot?

Answer (score 0):

Since there are no other types you are passing type arguments to,
`ConversationState` must have no type parameters, hence the error.

```
new ConversationState<ConfState>
// should be changed to 
new ConversationState
```

Comment: No it will raise another error, Argument of type 'ConversationState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MiddlewareHandler | Middleware'.
  Property 'onTurn' is missing in type 'ConversationState' but required in type 'Middleware'. [2345]  because am using                                                                                                   adapter.use(conversationState)